# how to add a custom file type in jupyterlab launcher?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I work with jupyterlab on daily basis and I would like to customize my launcher to add extra file type. Right now I need to create a new text file and then change the extention.

If anyone can help me add Yaml for example ?

[image]

Comment: I guess you can make a pull request to JupyterLab to include it, or write an extension. For Julia there was a recent PR which added icon here: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/10397